# Math.round is not working as i want to

Tags: java, math

Whenever a double is returned from the calculateVolume() it gets a value for example 1.0, this need to be displayed as 1.00 (2 decimals instead of 1).
It's probably quite easy but i'm not seeing what i'm doing wrong right now. Can someone help me out and give a short explanation. Thanks a lot!

```
public class Block extends Shape {
private double length;
private double width;
private double height;


public Block(double length, double width, double height){
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}

@Override
public double calculateVolume(){ 

    return Math.round((length * width * height)* 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't post any code that even attempts to display the value.

Comment: Exactly , you can use `DecimalFormat` to show. or System.printf

Comment: The value doesn't contain a format to say how it should be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class (and make sure you go check out that documentation!) to format your numbers for output. You can also use the standard [`String` formatting options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for less complex requirements (but I prefer `DecimalFormat`).

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // Two decimal places
System.out.print(fmt.format(calculateVolume()));
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have two options to solve that:**

**1.** Take a look at the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) documentation for more details.

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.print(df.format(calculateVolume()));
```

**2.** Another option is this one: [Formatting Numeric Print](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", calculateVolume());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", yourVariable);
```

Also you can find different formatting methods at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html